# How to count a total number of repeating text in excel

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

Example:
A1  Apple
A2  Apple
A3  Pear
A4  Banana
A5  Orange 
A6  Banana
A7  Apple

I don't understand how to use a formula to tell me how many different kinds of fruit there are, using a function in excel. Every variation of using COUNT and COUNTIF and SUM just confuses me further but I feel like there is a really simple answer I just can't figure it out! Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to count the number of unique values in a range of cells (named "data" in the example below), you can use a formula that uses COUNTIF and SUMPRODUCT.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(data,data))
```

> Working from the inside out, COUNTIF looks inside the data range and
>   counts the number of times that each individual value appears in data.
>   The result is an array or numbers, that might look something like
>   this: {1,2,2,3,3,3}.
>
> After COUNTIF is finished the results are used as a divisor with 1 as
>   the numerator. Values that appear in data once appear in the array as
>   1, but values that appear multiple times will appear as fractional
>   values that correspond to the mutliple. (i.e. a value that appears 5
>   times in data will generate 5 items in the array with a value of 1/5 =
>   .2).
>
> Finally, the SUMPRODUCT function sums all values in the array and
>   returns the result

Please check the following website for more information.
https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-values-in-a-range-with-countif